# Django Rest Framework - How to call method model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to call a method from a template. I have the following codes:

models.py

```
class Operation(Base):
    ...
    hash_code = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4)
    ...

    def open_operation(self, user):
       ...
       pass
```

views.py

```
class OperationOpenView(APIView):
"""
patch:
"""

    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = OperationOpenFilter

    def patch(self, request, id):
        user = request.user
        operation = Operation.objects.get(pk=id)
        serializer = OperationOpenSerializer(operation, 
                     data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            serializer.instance.open_operation(user)
            return Response(data={'operation': operation, 'user': user}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(code=400, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
class OperationOpenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Operation
        fields = ('id', )
        depth = 1
```

filters.py

```
class OperationOpenFilter(filters.FilterSet):

id = filters.NumberFilter(
    label='id',
    required=True,
    help_text='ID'
)

class Meta:
    model = Operation
    fields = ['id',]
```

urls.py

```
path(r'operations/open', views.OperationOpenView.as_view()),
```

tests.py

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_view(client_api_logged):
    response = client_api_logged.patch('/api/operations/open', kwargs= 
    {'id': '1'})
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

I'm not getting it to work, getting the error:

"TypeError at /api/operations/open
patch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'"

any light at the end of the tunnel?

thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your url:

```
path(r'operations/open/<int:id>/', views.OperationOpenView.as_view()),
```

And in `tests.py`:

```
response = client_api_logged.patch('/api/operations/open/1/', kwargs={'id':1})
```

#### Explanation:

The patch method takes 3 parameters (self, request, id). Python(object reference) provides 'self', Django provides 'request' and the URL needs to provide the 'id'. The URL mapping in the post didn't include an 'id' so Django complains about a missing parameter. *from comment of Ben*

Comment: A small expansion: The patch method takes 3 parametere (self, request, id). Python provides 'self', Django provides 'request' and the URL needs to provide the 'id'. The URL mapping in the post didn't include an 'id' so Django complains about a missing parameter.

Comment: @Ben thanks. I am adding the explanation to the answer.